# Estou com um problema com esse slideshow

Tags: css, background, slideshow

Faz tempo que venho tentando achar o problema mais n consigo (nota: sou novato nesta área), acontece que quando o background troca a imagem, num pequeno intervalo ele da tipo um flash, e como mudei de jquery para css, pois não estava conseguindo suavizar o efeito slider, esse flash está me irritando. E o interessante que  só acontece no primeiro loop, depois ele continua a trocar imagens normalmente. Enfim está aqui o código, espero que me ajudem.

```
.body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-image: url("imagens/fundo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    animation: linear;
    animation-name: body;
    animation-duration: 30s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
    animation-delay: .1s;
}`
`@keyframes body{
    0%  {background-image: url("imagens/slide.jpg"); background-size: 100% 100%;}   
    20%  {background-image: url("imagens/slide1.jpg"); background-size: 100% 100%;}
    40%  {background-image: url("imagens/slide2.jpg"); background-size: 100% 100%;}
    60%  {background-image: url("imagens/slide3.jpg"); background-size: 100% 100%;}
    80%  {background-image: url("imagens/slide4.jpg"); background-size: 100% 100%;}
    100%{background-image: url("imagens/slide5.jpg"); background-size: 100% 100%;}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Acontece que as imagens estão sendo baixadas no momento em que o CSS troca o frame. Adicione este código na página só para garantir que as imagens já estejam carregadas e assim evitar que na hora de trocar via css, haja este pequeno flash.

```html
<div class="pre-load-images" style="display:none">
  <img src="imagens/slide.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="imagens/slide1.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="imagens/slide2.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="imagens/slide3.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="imagens/slide4.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="imagens/slide5.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```